# Find space in string, remove everything after it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, variables, strip

Hoping this would be simple, but doesnt seem to be.

I've got a variable in vb.net 'contactname'.
format is like "John Smith"

I want to get just the forename from this, but cant seem to do it.

I've found and adapted some examples from google, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Will you also have to deal with "John Paul Smith" or "P. John Smith"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the string on spaces and take the first element:

```
contactname.Split(" "c)(0)
```

Comment: That works exactly how i wanted it - thank you kind sir

Comment: @John - that's what the `(0)` was for. Split returns an array, and so far as I can recall, accessing elements of an array in VB is via `()`.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever, can you tell me what is the "c" for?

Comment: @chiapa - in VB, `" "` is a `String`. `" "c` is a `Char`. In C# they use different delimiters (`""` vs `''`) but in VB they use the same delimiters and a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Could use Regex if you like:

```
Public Shared Function RegexGetForename(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim a = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(\w+)")
    If a.IsMatch(str) Then
        Return a.Match(str).Value
    Else
        Return vbNull
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim forename as string
Dim i = contactname.IndexOf(" ")
            If i <> -1 Then
                forename = contactname.Substring(0, i)
                MsgBox(forename)

            End If
```

try it

Comment: Dim i = contactname.IndexOf(" ") this line has issue